# Qt Enconding Error when returning spanish characters from server php script

Tags: qt

So I've been doing some tests regarding enconding errors that I've seen around ñ charcater using CURL, Qt and sever side PHP. I've finally got a super minimalistic example where the error is in the Qt side ONLY. Maybe some one can help me out.

The Qt Code is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString address = "http://localhost/api_test/test.php";
    QUrl url(address);
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.post(request, QByteArray());
    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, QCoreApplication::quit);
    a.exec();
    if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError){
        qDebug() << "The output";
        qDebug() << QString(reply->readAll()).toUtf8();
    }
    else{
        qDebug() << reply->error() << reply->errorString();
    }
    delete reply;

    return 0;
}
```

On the server side, test.php is as follows:

```
<?php

   $data = file_get_contents("uploaded.json");
   echo "$data\n";

?>
```

Where "uploaded.json" is a plain text file that contains

```
{"name" : "Ariel ñoño", "age" : 58}
```

The curl command now works as expected

```
ariel@ColoLaptop:/home/web/api_test$ curl http://localhost/api_test/test.php
{"name" : "Ariel ñoño", "age" : 58}
```

But when I run the Qt Application, this happens:

```
The output
"{\"name\" : \"Ariel \xC3\xB1o\xC3\xB1o\", \"age\" : 58} \n\n"
```

Again the ñ characters get screwed. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the Qt Code or how can I interpret the returned byte string correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "ñ" is unicode text so using `toUtf8()` won't do the trick. You have to use a QTextDecoder

```cpp
qDebug() << "The output";
QTextCodec* codec = QTextCodec::codecForLocale();
QTextDecoder* decoder = codec->makeDecoder();
QString text = decoder->toUnicode(reply->readAll());
qDebug() << text;
```

Output:

```
The output
"{\"name\" : \"Ariel ñoño\", \"age\" : 58}\n"
```

Comment: This will not work when the console can not display the characters in the current locale. qDebug() is only meant to be used for debugging output.

Comment: @chehrlic Hmm, okay, but what does this have to do with my answer. My code works even if qDebug() is not used but any other element that allows visualizing the text such as a QLabel, QTextEdit, etc.

Comment: QLabel and co uses a QString so no need to convert something to the current locale at all. Json is encoded as utf-8 by default on the other side so label->setText(QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll())) is enough.

Comment: @chehrlic Obviously if we take as information that the standard json is being used but the OP is not using it, it is only printing a content file :-): `echo "$data\n";`

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc, you really saved by backon twice now!! Much appreciated!!!